# Weird default shadow on new Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow

Since the last update of **Unity 3D 2019 3.8f1 Personal**, I have a problem of shadow and directional light. Each time I create a new project, the default directional light is weird and change my white color into a grey color:
[**image of the default settings project**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXg2o.png)

So I remove the directional light and add a new and the problem of the color was solved. However the back of all my component is still very dark, like as if they are no reflection. And whatever I change(intensity, color, shadow, rotation...), the dark dark "shadow" still there at the opposite of the light:
[**image with the new directional light**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KUaN.png)

If anybody can help me, it will be a real pleasure :D !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create a new project you start a "zero project" and unity applies a standard. You will then choose how to do everything.

3 fast things

A) This question does not go well on stackoverflow. study thebasics of unity, find some good tutorials on light

B) the light is dependent on those options you see on the right.

C) the light depends on the bake of the latter.

---

Stackoverflow isn't Google.
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=unity+light+tutorial